# MVCGrid.net - Grid doesn't page results, shows all records and pager also

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvcgrid.net

The grid is being displayed which has pager enabled but displays all records without paging. Also the pager is displayed. Code for RegisterGrid() method is as below:-

```
public static void RegisterGrids()
        {
            GridDefaults defaultSet1 = new GridDefaults()
            {
                Paging = true,
                ItemsPerPage = 5,
                NoResultsMessage = "Sorry, no results were found"
            };

            MVCGridDefinitionTable.Add("grdFiles", new MVCGridBuilder<FilesModel>(defaultSet1)
            .WithAuthorizationType(AuthorizationType.AllowAnonymous)
            .AddColumns(cols =>
            {
                cols.Add("FileName")
                    .WithValueExpression(p => p.Name.ToString());
                cols.Add("LastModified").WithHeaderText("LastModified")
                    .WithValueExpression(p => p.LastModified.ToString());
                cols.Add("Size").WithHeaderText("Size")
                    .WithValueExpression(p => p.Size.ToString());
            })
            .WithRetrieveDataMethod((context) =>
            {
                var res = DisplayFiles();
                return new QueryResult<FilesModel>()
                {
                    Items = res,
                    TotalRecords = res.Count // if paging is enabled, return the total number of records of all pages
                };
            })
            );
        }
```

View Code is:

```
@model IEnumerable<FileViewerWeb.Models.FilesModel>

@using MVCGrid.Web;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<div class="well well-lg" style="padding-top:10px">
    <h2>Explore Uploaded Files</h2>
</div>

@Html.MVCGrid("grdFiles")
```

Controller Code :-

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your way of generating the list to a query and then at the end pass the query via a `ToList()`

```
var result = new QueryResult<FilesModel>();
var query = db.FilesModel.AsQueryable();
```

You are missing the code

```
if (options.GetLimitOffset().HasValue)
{
    var limitOffset = options.GetLimitOffset().Value;
    var limitRowCount = options.GetLimitRowcount().Value;
    query = query
        .Skip(limitOffset)
        .Take(limitRowCount);
}
```

Finally, at the point of returning use

```
result.Items = query.ToList();
result.TotalRecords = result.Items.Count();
return result;
```

Comment: `result.TotalRecords = result.Items.Count();`  This is not correct. It should be something like `result.TotalRecords = unfilteredQuery.Count();`, since the paginator would display something 1 of 50 (total: 50) instead of 1 of 50 (total: 1234).

Answer (score 0):

When you are using skip you have firstly to use orderby.

```
if (options.GetLimitOffset().HasValue)
{
    var limitOffset = options.GetLimitOffset().Value;
    var limitRowCount = options.GetLimitRowcount().Value;
    query = query.OrderBy(c=>c.name) //or add any column you prefer to order the list
        .Skip(limitOffset)
        .Take(limitRowCount);
}
```